# Get only categories from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have three different categories in firebase. I only need to get one. Now I'm at the stage when I brought everything into an array of objects.
[Firebase json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4By88.png)

```
var database = firebase.database();

let userRef = database.ref('pizzas/')

userRef.once('value', function (snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

I need to get the 'category' of each of the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
userRef.once('value', ((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val().category)
 });
});
```

Using `forEach` you can iterate inside the snapshot and get the value of `category`.